# embed additional second dataframe into plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, mousehover, data-ingestion

I want my plot to retrieve data from one dataframe, but hovering over the data i want it to incorperate data from both data frames.

example:[image]

which results from

```
fig = px.scatter(X_reduced_df, x='EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE', y='score_IF', color= 'anomaly_class_IF', hover_data=['score_IF','delta',
                                                                                                                'omicron',
                                                                                                                'NH4-N (titr.)(W)_Zusatzparameter-ESRI',
                                                                                                                'P ges. filtr. (photom.)(W) mA_Zusatzparameter-ESRI',
                                                                                                                'BSB5 (mit Verd) DIN 1899_Zusatzparameter-ESRI',
                                                                                                                'N org. (Ber. TKN)(W)_Zusatzparameter-ESRI'
                                                                                                               ], #range_x=['2015-12-01', '2016-01-15'],
                 title="Default Display with Gaps")
fig.show()
```

Here i want the value "delta" to be associated with additional info on "delta" from another dataframe, i.e. i want "delta= 0, add info" where *add info* is a list or a dataframecolumn, or similar.(its a list of names associated with a double, like as:
column name: delta
column entries
gamma: 1.2

alpha: 1.3

.

.

.

)
basically its a correlation matrix. and i want the correlations associated with each entry to be displayed.
The second dataframe, the correlation matrix is regrettably not the same columns as the original dataframe, hence not joinable. i want column names to be associated with the add info. i thought about categories, but i cannot see how that could help for a compact add info.
also i do not want to meddle with the column names(like in forcing a rename with the add info).
the plotly library only allows for one dataframe as input, right? how can i add my add info, the i way i described?